# How to go the end of the current line in a file and check the character in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, ifstream

In my project, I have two structs:

```
struct spell {
    string name;
    string effect;
};

struct spellbook {
    string title;
    string author;
    int pages;
    struct spell* s;
}
```

The spellbook and spell objects are arrays in this program. I'm reading information from a file and putting it into these two structs. An example of the file is:

```
2                               //Number of spellbooks
Dark_Secrets Grady 357          //Title author pages
Evil_Force Dark                //Spell name and effect
Grimoire Thompson 1967 
Heavenly_Glow Light
Water_Ray Water
```

So the spellbook lines end with an integer (page number), while the spell lines end with a letter (The number at the top of the file is taken care of by another method). My plan for distinguishing between them was to check the last char in the line, and seeing if it was a digit. If it was, then I would add it to the spellbook struct. If not, then I would add it to the spell struct. As far as implementing this, I'm not sure how. Here is my add to spellbook struct method: (I have to have 2 different methods for this assignment)

```
void get_spellbook_data(spellbook* sb, int n, ifstream &file) //Int n is the number of spellbooks {
    char end_line;
    int i = 0;
    //Jump to end of current line. I tried using file,seekg(-1, ios_base::end) but it got me to the end of the file, not the line
    file.get(end_line); //Get last character in the line
    //Jump back to the beginning of the current line
    if (isdigit(end_line)) { //If current line is spellbook
        file >> sb[i].title >> sb[i].author >> sb[i].pages;
           i++;
    }
    else {//If its a spell line
        //Skip this line and advance to the next one
    }
 }
```

That's my current idea so far. The method to add spells would basically be the same as this except checking if the current line does not end with a digit. I feel like there is a better method to get the information, but I'm not exactly sure of how to implement it.

Comment: Can you change the format. So the spellbook line has the number of spells in it. That would make it really easy to parse.

Comment: A file is a stream. You can not tell what is at the end of the line without first reading the whole line. So you read the line (into std::string) then you check the last character. Then you have to parse the string to put in in the appropriate structure. Easier to know what structure it is going into first and simply read it directly.

Comment: It's pretty unstable to determine the format of a line from the last character. E.g. you might run into problems if you end a spell line with the spell intensity, later on. You need a section based structure like in a config file, e.g [spellbook] \n title author pages \n [spells] \n spellname spelleffect \n spellname spelleffect \n... \n [spellbook] \n title author pages \n ... . This way a standard config parser can be used to read the file. Alternatively you may think of using a xml parser if the structure gets more complicated.

Comment: Maybe look up how general parsers work. Generally you have a tokeniser, then a state based acceptor. In this case, you would tokenise the input to 'word', 'integer', and 'end-of-line'. Once you have a sequence like that, you can define states like 'start', 'first-word', 'second-word', 'got-spell' (if EOL was next), 'got-spellbook' (if integer was next), and other states as needed (such as 'error-find-next-eol'). ...Or maybe that's more complex than you're looking for, but it's very expandable in the future.

Comment: I can't change the format of the file, unfortunately. As far as checking for structure, could I just do if (file >> sb[0].title >> sb[0].authpr >> sb[0].pages) I've tried that before and it didn't seem to work

Comment: Maybe it is an option to confront the creator of the structure with the fact that it is far from optimal. Think about writing a manual for the file format or letting some other write a spell file for you: "[...] The line which defines a spellbook must end with a digit but all other lines must not end with a digit, else parsing fails [...]". Do you see that this may be very confusing to others or yourself in about 6 month? Use a clear and intuitive structure. There is no relationship between an entity beeing a spellbook and a line ending with a digit. That it's the case is just by luck.

Answer (score 0):

Typical way to read a file line by line:

```cpp
std::string line;
while (true) {
  if (!std::getline(ifs, line)) {
    // either eof or error, check ifs.eof()
    // need to handle this somehow, leaving this up to you
  }

  // Now you have the whole text line in the line.
  if (!line.empty()) break;

  // the line was empty for some reason, continue to next line, until
  // you get non-empty line, eof or error
}

// Now you have non-empty line. Check that the last char is digit...
if (std::isdigit(line.back()) {
  // the last character is digit
}
// but I'd split line into space separated tokens and check if there is 2 or 3 tokens.
```

Comment: I'll try this method out, thank you. After I get the last character, would I just do file >> sb[0].title > sb[0].author >> sb[0].pages to get all the struct data fields? And then If I run into a case where the last line isn't a digit, how do I move the line being read forward?

Comment: No, the line is already read from file so you can't do just "file >> something". No matter last difit is number or not. You need to create std::istringstream over the "line" and read from it.

Comment: And how would I do that? Apologies, I'm new to c++

Comment: same way as you did with ifstream, but pass line as parameter to constructor. for more info read the docs about std::istringstream on the cppreference.com

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I'd read a whole line in at a time, and then determine if I'm looking at a book or a spell line. So the code may look like:

```
struct spell {
    std::string name;
    std::string effect;
    spell(std::string str) {
        std::istringstream strm(str);
        strm >> name >> effect;
    }
};

struct spellbook {
    std::string title;
    std::string author;
    int pages;
    std::vector<spell> spells; // vector for nicer code and a cleaner name
    spellbook(std::string str) {
        std::istringstream strm(str);
        strm >> title >> author >> pages;
    }
};

bool is_book(std::string str) {
    return isdigit(str.back());
}

int main() {
    std::vector<spellbook> books;
    ifstream fhand("Some/File/Location.txt");
    std::string line;
    while(std::getline(fhand, line)) {
        if(is_book(line)) {
            books.push_back(spellbook(line));
        } else {
            books.back().spells.push_back(spell(line));
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a live example (using stdin instead of a file): https://ideone.com/s9qk7Y

Comment: I can't change any of the structs, or change the arrays into vectors. These are all requirements for my project.

Comment: @mad The idea is still the same. I just changed things to make it easier to show. But this all still works with your style of the structs. You'll just need to update the code

Comment: One more thing: When the line is for a spell I just want it to be skipped because I have to have a separate function to get input for the spells. So if the current line is not a spellbook, how do I advance until I get another line that is a spellbook?

Comment: You could just swap all the code in the `else` in the loop with `continue;`. But I'm not sure how you'd then go back and read the spells later... It's probably easier to read it all as it comes in @mad.